# What is the initial own weight of a transaction in IOTA?

Tags: iota-network

According to the [white paper](https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf) for IOTA the initial own weight of any transaction is 3<sup>n</sup>, where *n* is a positive integer. However, in section 4 it says that the own weight value is capped to one to prevent double-spending attacks. That disproves the initial premise of weight.

What is the actual own weight value of a transaction in IOTA then?

Comment: You quoted where the initial own weight was 3^n.  But can you please quote the section that caps the weight at 1?  I don't mean the paragraph that discusses it capped at 1 (I found that) but the passage that actually caps own weight at 1.  Maybe the context will help us to understand it better.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't understand what you're asking for exactly. The discussion about capping own weight to 1 is with reference to the double-spending attack scenario and also making IOTA Quantum attack proof. Not sure which passage you're looking for.

Comment: "However, in section 4 it says that the own weight value is capped to one to prevent double-spending attacks."

This is your own quote, man.  Show me where in section 4 it says this.

Comment: Yes my quote is exclusively mine and the whitepaper only implies that rather than saying the exact words. The whole idea of preventing double-spending attack is based on weight capping.

Answer (score 2):

The current implementation sets the own weight of any transaction to `1` for reasons of simplicity.

Future plans might introduce a more sophisticated weight calculation algorithm, but this is still part of on-going research.

Comment: I was going through the Anatomy of a transaction as given here - https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/the-anatomy-of-a-transaction. I didn't see weight as part of the transaction fields which seemed strange to me. How is weight even considered for any transaction then?

Comment: Weights are calculated on the fly, and only used for tip selection, which is why once you've got your tips there is no need to store the weights.