# How is the initial own weight of any transaction calculated?

Tags: iota-network

According to the IRI, could you briefly explain how the initial weights for each transaction is calculated?

The [Whitepaper](https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf) states that the weight of a transaction is the amount of work invested into it and also marks the transaction importance. However it doesn't go into much details from there.

Comment: @Zauz This question was created due to this reply: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/what-is-the-initial-own-weight-of-a-transaction-in-iota#comment1457_1235 But actually I do agree that the question should be answered with an explanation over there.

Comment: I know and I do too. We just have to wait for CFB to edit his answer or for somebody else to answer it. Making another question asking the same thing makes no sense which is why I voted to close.